# How to insert and search in elasticsearch in one thread use Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to insert to database some records and search this records. But due to the fact that the search is performed in another thread I find nothing. I have code:

```
IndexResponse indexResponse = client.prepareIndex(indexName, documentType)
            .setSource(request.toJSONString())
            .setOperationThreaded(false)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
            .setTypes(documentType)
            .setQuery(boolQuery)
            .setSize(number)
            .setFrom(offset)
            .addSort("date", SortOrder.ASC)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

And I doesn't find last record. How to setting 1 thread for insert and search?

Comment: And what makes you have these assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is that index is not updated at the moment when you are actually giving a call to search API, so if you update your index it will work.

Add

```
setRefresh(true)
```

to your `prepareIndex` call.

PS: Although the above solution will work but its recommended that you should do not use it in general practice, because it will have a performance impact.
So its better to rely on elastic search for updating the indices which is a background operation. Well you could use it for testing purpose, but it shoould not be adopted as a genral practice.